# bash array from string keeping only content between delimiters

Tags: arrays, bash, mediawiki

I'm trying to create a bash script that uses info pulled from Wikipedia via curl to help sort my music collection. I've gotten it to reliably return the information I want, but because of Wikipedia's formatting, there is sometimes information I want to discard. It is also not always formatted consistently; sometimes it is on multiple lines, and sometimes only one, but the information I want is consistently delimited between "[[" and "]]". I want to keep only the text between [[ and ]] and ignore the rest. All of the solutions I've found so far use sed and rely on consistent formatting. Basically what I want to do is take a long string formatted:

```
{{[[abcd]]efgh[[hijk]]lmno
[[pqrs]]
[[tuvw]]yz}}
```

and create an array with the values

```
abcd
hijk
pqrs
tuvw
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Why isn't `sed` acceptable? What inconsistencies caused it to fail and how?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Suggest `grep -o` piped to `cut`.

Comment: @Cyrus I don't see how you can post this comment, and also post an answer. Use your CV's instead please.

Comment: grep -o piped to cut -c was what I was using initially. It worked great for 70% of the outputs, but failed miserably on the other 30. Sorry for not including that info. This is my first post on stackoverflow. @Cyrus thanks for the feedback and for offering the solution. I'll try to be more thorough with questions in the future. Everyone's journey to expertise has to pass through novicehood at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep and a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE):

```
grep -Po '(?<=\[\[).*?(?=]])' file
```

Output:

```
abcd
hijk
pqrs
tuvw
```

Comment: This accomplished exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!